# Watermark text repeated diagonally css/html

Tags: html, css, watermark

How can I achieve the following watermark text ("howbloggerz") with css/html?

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this can be done with HTML/CSS only as it requires modifying the actual image (otherwise viewers can save the image without the watermark). Is a server sided solution possible?

Comment: It is not required to modify the actual image. Viewers are allowed to save it without watermark in this case :)

Comment: This is exactly what i needed to make it obvious an editing copy is displayed instead of the official one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set the size of your container and float your text using absolute positioning while [transforming](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) your text with rotate.

```css
#watermark {
  height: 450px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#watermark img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
#watermark p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="watermark">
  <img src="http://www.topchinatravel.com/pic/city/dalian/attraction/people-square-1.jpg">
  <p>This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark. This is a watermark.</p>
</div>
```

**Note:** For repeating text, I would suggest using either JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Your watermark text can be selected, you might want to fix that with pointer-events: none;

Comment: You can also fix it with user-select: none;

Comment: Keep in mind that `user-select` is still a working draft and that most browsers will require a vendor prefix or different name for use.

Answer (score 32):

This is pretty similar to Daerik's answer, but I wanted to avoid using an extra element, and automate the watermark text generation.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.watermarked').forEach(function(el) {
  el.dataset.watermark = (el.dataset.watermark + ' ').repeat(300);
});
```

```css
.watermarked {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.watermarked img {
  width: 100%;
}

.watermarked::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -75%;
  left: -75%;
  
  display: block;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  content: attr(data-watermark);
  
  opacity: 0.7;
  line-height: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="watermarked" data-watermark="howbloggerz">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this might be even easier :)

Comment: `Array.from()` and `String.prototype.repeat()` were introduced in the same ECMAScript 2015 standard (ES6, or ECMA-262), so I'm curious as to why hesitate to use one and not the other? Otherwise, awesome answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, good question! This was an oversight on my part. I'd gotten so used to having `Array.from` polyfilled, that it completely slipped my mind that support was essentially identical. I've updated the post to use `String.prototype.repeat`.

Comment: Works great. Though I had to avoid using any `JavaScript` since the OP was asking for `CSS/HTML`. That's why I added my suggestion to use `JavaScript` or `jQuery`.

Comment: This did not work for me. I noticed that it also doesn't work in your example when I use "Expand snippet"... no watermark is shown.

Comment: @WilliamK you're probably running some ancient browser. Works on latest Firefox, Edge, Chrome

Comment: Tried both Firefox and Firefox Dev. The demo worked ok, but when clicking to "Expand" it did not work. What else can I say?

Comment: @WilliamK sounds like a bug with SO's snippet thing to me. Possibly the expand is re-rendering the html without running the JS again? Not sure.

Answer (score 26):

I'm now using svg as a background image. Plain CSS:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='100px' width='100px'><text transform='translate(20, 100) rotate(-45)' fill='rgb(245,45,45)' font-size='20'>watermark</text></svg>");
}
```

```html
<body style="width:100%;height:100%"></body>
```

Javascript to set the background:

```js
function watermark(text) {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var bg = "url(\"data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='100px' width='100px'>" +
    "<text transform='translate(20, 100) rotate(-45)' fill='rgb(245,45,45)' font-size='20' >" + text + "</text></svg>\")";
  body.style.backgroundImage = bg
}

//for this test
var input = document.getElementById('a');
watermark(input.value);
input.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  watermark(this.value);
});
```

```html
<body style="width:100%;height:100%">
  <input id="a" value="change me" />
</body>
```

Comment: this does not print on pdfs

Comment: @Extrangeplanet this is CSS/HTML and has nothing to do with PDF, you are probably using a library to convert it, check your library support.

Comment: This is by far the most elegant solution. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

If it is only to lay a text over the image, here is another possible css option with `drop-shadow` and a pseudo (`text-shadow` works too)

```css
.watermarked:after {/* draw the watermark at screen*/
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  content: 'watermarked watermarked watermarked';
  word-spacing: 3em;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  filter: 
  drop-shadow(2em 3em  #000) 
  drop-shadow(4em 6em  #000) 
  drop-shadow(8em 12em #000) 
  drop-shadow(-15em -24em #000)
  ;
}

/* makeup */
.watermarked {
  width: max-content;
  border: solid;
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img,
.watermarked:after {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="watermarked" data-watermark="howbloggerz">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
     Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.watermarked')).forEach(function(el) {
        el.dataset.watermark = (el.dataset.watermark + ' ').repeat(300);
    });
```

```css
.watermarked::before {
    position: fixed;
    top: -75%;
    left: -75%;

    display: block;
    width: 300%;
    height: 300%;

    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    content: attr(data-watermark);

    font-size: 30px;
    opacity: 0.75;
    line-height: 4em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
Form and Watermarks
</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Form Demo</h1>
<form method="post">
    First Name: <input name="first" type="text" /><br>
    Last name: <input name="last" type="text" />
    <br />
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<div class='watermarked' data-watermark='watermark..' ></div>

</body>
</html>
```

It works great but not with html form. The form elements become disabled. Check this out.

Comment: This issue is also happening with hyperlinks etc... I got the problem fixed by adding  pointer-events: none;

Answer (score 0):

```
CSS:-
.watermarked::before {
    position: fixed;
    top: -75%;
    left: -75%;

    display: block;
    width: 300%;
    height: 300%;

    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    content: attr(data-watermark);

    font-size: 30px;
    opacity: 0.15;
    line-height: 4em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #ff0523;
    z-index:-1;
}

HTML:-
<div class="watermarked" data-watermark="Watermark.."></div>

SCRIPT:-

<script>        
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.watermarked')).forEach(function(el) {
        el.dataset.watermark = (el.dataset.watermark + ' ').repeat(10000);
    });
</script>
```

> watermark position should be as fixed and display with & height should
>   be your screen size. Then watermark will be printed in your whole
>   report or something.